# Typescript Generics - Extending a class

Tags: generics, typescript

As an example, I have the following class:

```
module app.components.base {
    export class BaseController<S extends IAppScope, A> {
        public data:string;

        constructor(public $scope: S, public service: A, public $state: ng.ui.IStateService, public $ionicHistory) {
            console.log('Base Controller Loaded!');
            console.log($scope);
            $scope.vm = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this separate class:

```
module app.components.properties {

    export class PropertiesController extends base.BaseController<IPropertiesScope, app.services.PropertyService> {

    }
}
```

So, in my mind, this says "The Properties Controller extends the Base Controller. The Properties Controller therefore should have `this.$scope`, and `this.$scope` should be of type `IPropertiesScope` since the generic type `S` inherits the `IPropertiesScope` interface`."

However, `$scope` is undefined in the constructor of my base class. Why is this value undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $scope is undefined in the constructor of my base class. Why is this value undefined?

This is because of the way angular's default dependency injection works. Even though *you know the constructor arguments* and `TypeScript` knows the constructor arguments, all that angular will see is [in code](http://bit.ly/1cyq67x) :

```
function PropertiesController() {
   _super.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You can see that TypeScript will pass thorugh the arguments just fine, however angular will see `PropertiesController()` and *not dependency inject anything*.

Fix: Have an explicit constructor

Alternatively have an explicit `static $inject` member on the class https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E